# Использование разны версий библиотек в VS

Tags: c++, visual-studio, dll, компоновщик, library

В **Windows** нужно использовать возможности [RTABMap](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Installation#windows) в своей программе, для этого хочу использовать их библиотеку примерно как в [этом туториале](https://github.com/introlab/rtabmap/wiki/Cplusplus-RGBD-Mapping), но возможно создавая решение не через CMake, а сразу в VS.

Я установил **RTABMap-0.18.0-win64.exe** и получил папку RTABMap, в которой есть **lib** и **include** файлы от самой RTABMap и рядом с **exe** файлом множество **dll** от зависимостей.

Возник ряд вопросов:

1. Правильно ли я понимаю, что так как в **.h файлах RTABMap** присутствует подключение заголовочных файлов зависимостей, то мне придётся установить эти зависимости для создания своей программы, несмотря на то, что exe файл RTABMap уже работает?
2. Если **lib** файлы RTABMap скомпилированы в VS одной из последних версий(2015 или 2019), **lib** и **dll** некоторых зависимостей в **VS 2015**, а некоторых в **VS 2019** -  будет ли работать такой набор библиотек в моём проекте на **VS 2019**?

Comment: к 1 вопросу: когда подключил .h файлы RTABMap, то оказалось что в них подключены другие .h файлы, например от opencv,  и VS  не знала что это такое -> Мне нужно получить эти заголовочные файлы, скачав зависимости

Comment: Как раз думал, что RTABMap сам всё установил, раз успешно запустился.
Спасибо!